# While parsing modifiers for field city: for modifier "readonly": Unknown field type in domain

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Working on a module for Odoo 14 CE

My module depends from another module called "base_locations"

base_locations extends the functionalities related to inserting data about cities and regions in the standard Odoo but it's distributed by the Odoo Community Association, so I assume it's pretty standard stuff

In one of my views I have a "city" field

```
<field name="city"/>
```

The field "city" is defined in a model belonging to the base_location module

But when I try to access the view, this error pops up in the web GUI

```
Error: While parsing modifiers for field city: for modifier "readonly": Unknown field type in domain
_registerModifiers@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/basic/basic_renderer.js:633:23
_renderFieldWidget@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/basic/basic_renderer.js:727:30
_renderFieldWidget@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form/form_renderer.js:530:21
OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:90:38
_renderInnerGroupField@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form/form_renderer.js:677:24
_renderInnerGroup/<@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form/form_renderer.js:641:29
_renderInnerGroup@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form/form_renderer.js:613:23
_renderTagGroup@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form/form_renderer.js:866:25
_renderNode@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form/form_renderer.js:722:29
_renderNode@http://localhost:8069/mail/static/src/widgets/form_renderer/form_renderer.js:140:21
OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:123:38
_renderTagForm@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form/form_renderer.js:852:38
_renderNode@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form/form_renderer.js:722:29
_renderNode@http://localhost:8069/mail/static/src/widgets/form_renderer/form_renderer.js:140:21
OdooClass.extend/Class.include/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:123:38
_renderView@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form/form_renderer.js:1054:26
_render@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/abstract_renderer.js:141:20
_render@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/basic/basic_renderer.js:675:20
OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:90:38
start@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/abstract_renderer.js:55:33
OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:90:38
start@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form/form_renderer.js:53:28
OdooClass.extend/</prototype[name]</<@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/class.js:90:38
_widgetRenderAndInsert/<@http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/core/widget.js:440:25
```

If I comment out this city field, the view works

How do I go about this error message ?

Especially the first line is quite obscure to me

```
Error: While parsing modifiers for field city: for modifier "readonly": Unknown field type in domain
```

which parsing phase is this referring to, exactly ?

And field type ? Domain ?

I don't get what this mesage is refering to

Comment: I created a new database and in the new database it works without a glitch

Comment: the error came back

Comment: adding <field name="type" /> to the view, fixes it

I don't know why

Comment: this is happening to me with a computed many2many field and using the many2many tags widget. One of the field of the many2many model, has a domain with state field, but I'm using the widget, and gets only the name. IDK why haha